# What is the "opaa7g6" for in my terminal?

Tags: terminal, mac

Today when I'm taking a look at my terminal, I realized that there is a weird string in my shell prompt.

It seems that I've never seen this weird string before.

What is that for?

[image]

Comment: Good question, but I believe it has been asked before and the linked question explains it.

Comment: I am sorry I didn't get it in that question.